# Using an Imagemagick script for multiple photos

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I have imagemagick sequence of commands that cleanup a single image step by step:

```
#! /bin/bash

convert -unsharp 5 "base.jpg" "base.ppm"

convert -opaque white -fill white -fuzz 10% "base.ppm" "image1_step1.tif"

convert -fuzz 5% -fill "#816c51" -opaque "#816c51" "image1_step1.tif" "image1_step2.tif"
convert -fuzz 1.5% -fill "#816c51" -opaque "#5a4a3b" "image1_step2.tif" "image1_step3.tif"

convert -fuzz 12% -fill "black" -opaque "#1c110f" "image1_step3.tif" "image1_step4.tif"

convert image1_step4.tif image1_cleaned.jpg
```

I'd like to use this script on a couple hundred tif files in a particular folder. I'm not sure how to automate this, I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your convert commands in a `for` loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="/path/to/dir"
cd "$dir"
for file in *.jpg
do
    base=${file%*.jpg}
    convert ... "$base" "$base.ppm"
    convert ... "$base.ppm" "${base}_step1.tif"
    # etc
done
```

Comment: @Nimbuz: It looks good to me, but the last convert seems to be a no-op. Perhaps you mean for the second argument to be `"${base}_final.jpg"` which would be consistent with the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may do:

```
#!/bin/bash

VICTIM="$1"

if [ -z "$VICTIM" ]; then
    echo >&2 "Syntax: $0 <imagefile>"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -f "$VICTIM" ]; then
    echo >&2 "$VICTIM is not a regular file"
    exit 1
fi

VICTIM=$(readlink -f "$VICTIM")

DSTDIR=$(dirname "$VICTIM")

WORKDIR=$(mktemp -d /tmp/.workXXXXXX)

if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
    echo >&2 "Aiie, failed to create temporary directory"
    exit 1
fi

export WORKDIR

trap "rm -rf $WORKDIR" exit INT QUIT TERM

(
    cd $WORKDIR
    convert -unsharp 5 "$VICTIM" step1.ppm && \
    convert -opaque white -fill white -fuzz 10% step1.ppm step2.tif && \
    convert -fuzz 1.5% -fill "#816c51" -opaque "#5a4a3b" step2.tif step3.tif && \
    convert -fuzz 12% -fill "black" -opaque "#1c110f" step3.tif step4.tif
)

if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
    echo >&2 "Aiie, image processing failed"
    exit 1
fi

convert $WORKDIR/step4.tif $DSTDIR/CLEANED-$VICTIM

RC=$?
if [ "$RC" != "0" ]; then
   echo >&2 "Aiie, final conversion failed"
fi

exit $RC
```

Name this script "convert_one.sh" and invoke with:

```
for i in *.jpg; do sh convert_one.sh $i;done
```